# How to get the details from mysql using php as soon as user submits if there are millions of users

Tags: php, mysql

If the user submits details I will be able to save it in mysql but how can I get only those details on screen. The latest one. Suppose there are millions of users there might be some disturbance for slecting from mysql as so many users submit at a time. So can I any one suggest me how can I overcome this

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the details of that specific user you can give some kind of token generated randomly or [UUID](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) to this user when he enters the page and after that you will be able to do a SELECT with WHERE clause to get this information in a easy way or if you want get the last one from your table maybe you can use `LAST()` on mysql `SELECT LAST(columnName) FROM Table;`